# Problem executing goal wildfly swarm plugin, API incompatibility, java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, maven, microservices, wildfly-swarm, debezium

I am trying to build the `debezium-swarm-demo` app in the `debezium-examples` [github repository](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples)

The build does not finish and gives me `Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null`

The output generated by maven using the -e argument is as follows:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.example:debezium-swarm-demo >-------------------
[INFO] Building WildFly Swarm Example 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [debezium-swarm-demo] in [/home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/target/demo]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [163 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/anushka/SideProjects/Docker/debezium-examples/end-to-end-demo/debezium-swarm-demo/target/demo.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package (default) @ debezium-swarm-demo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.918 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-12T14:27:27+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package (default) on project debezium-swarm-demo: Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/wildfly-swarm-plugin/2018.5.0/wildfly-swarm-plugin-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-metadata/2018.5.0/fraction-metadata-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/meta-spi/2018.5.0/meta-spi-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2018.5.0/tools-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2018.5.0/bootstrap-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.6.1.Final/jboss-modules-1.6.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2/zip4j-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2018.5.0/spi-2018.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package (default) on project debezium-swarm-demo: Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/wildfly-swarm-plugin/2018.5.0/wildfly-swarm-plugin-2018.5.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-metadata/2018.5.0/fraction-metadata-2018.5.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/meta-spi/2018.5.0/meta-spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2018.5.0/tools-2018.5.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2018.5.0/bootstrap-2018.5.0.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.6.1.Final/jboss-modules-1.6.1.Final.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
urls[14] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
urls[15] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[17] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[18] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[19] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2/zip4j-1.3.2.jar
urls[20] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2018.5.0/spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[21] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
urls[22] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
urls[23] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/wildfly-swarm-plugin/2018.5.0/wildfly-swarm-plugin-2018.5.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-metadata/2018.5.0/fraction-metadata-2018.5.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/meta-spi/2018.5.0/meta-spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2018.5.0/tools-2018.5.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2018.5.0/bootstrap-2018.5.0.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.6.1.Final/jboss-modules-1.6.1.Final.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
urls[14] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
urls[15] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[17] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[18] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[19] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2/zip4j-1.3.2.jar
urls[20] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2018.5.0/spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[21] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
urls[22] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
urls[23] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2018.5.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/wildfly-swarm-plugin/2018.5.0/wildfly-swarm-plugin-2018.5.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-metadata/2018.5.0/fraction-metadata-2018.5.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/meta-spi/2018.5.0/meta-spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2018.5.0/tools-2018.5.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2018.5.0/bootstrap-2018.5.0.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.6.1.Final/jboss-modules-1.6.1.Final.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
urls[14] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
urls[15] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0.jar
urls[17] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0.jar
urls[18] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0.jar
urls[19] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2/zip4j-1.3.2.jar
urls[20] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2018.5.0/spi-2018.5.0.jar
urls[21] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
urls[22] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
urls[23] = file:/home/anushka/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession.<init> (DefaultRepositorySystemSession.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.optimizeSession (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:269)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.plugin.maven.MavenArtifactResolvingHelper.resolveAll (MavenArtifactResolvingHelper.java:167)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveAllArtifactsTransitively (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:46)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.DependencyManager.analyzeRemovableDependencies (DependencyManager.java:230)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.DependencyManager.analyzeDependencies (DependencyManager.java:120)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.BuildTool.analyzeDependencies (BuildTool.java:306)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.BuildTool.build (BuildTool.java:240)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.tools.BuildTool.build (BuildTool.java:191)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.plugin.maven.PackageMojo.executeSpecific (PackageMojo.java:214)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.plugin.maven.AbstractSwarmMojo.execute (AbstractSwarmMojo.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: I have tried deleting the m2 repositories, and downloading them fresh, but doesn't work. I have also tried updating all dependencies to their latest version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're probably using Maven 3.6, which isn't supported in this ancient version of WildFly Swarm.
You can:

- use Maven 3.5
- or you can update to the latest version of Thorntail (yes, WildFly Swarm got renamed).

To update automatically, you can run:
`mvn io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final:migrate-from-wildfly-swarm`

Comment: The update approach didnt work for me (probably my setup) but downgrading to 3.5.3 did thx

Comment: Yes the simple solution is to downgrade to maven 3.5. Wildfly swarm is just incompatible with maven 3.6

Comment: After the update, `mvn thorntail:run` worked for me. Thanks.